# Hatcher Exercise 1.2.8

Tags: proof-verification, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, cw-complexes

I am trying to prove the following excersise (1.2.8) from Hatcher's Algebraic Topology:
*Given 2 tori $S^1\times S^1$ and identifying $S^1\times \{x_0\}$} compute the fundamental group*.

My approach is the following: Consider the first torus as an identified square via the scheme $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ and the second torus via $cdc^{-1}d^{-1}$.

To idintify the two circles is to "glue" $a$ with $c$. Here I must make 2 remarks. The first is that we could have picked $b,d$ with no substantial change to our proof. The second is that since Hatcher doesnt describe **how** to glue them I assume he means in the trivial way.

Therefore , having identified $a$ with $c$ with the arrow pointing the same way we get a new CW complex with scheme $bdad^{-1}b^{-1}a^{-1}$ and therefore, from Van Campen's theorem, we the fundamental group has representation $<a,b,d|bdad^{-1}b^{-1}a^{-1}>$.

I apologise for the quality of the figure:
[image]

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes , of course , I will fix the typo.

Comment: I think that $\dfrac{F\{a,b,d\}}{<<bdad^{-1}b^{-1}a^{-1}>>}=\dfrac{F\{a,b,d\}}{<<[bd,a]>>}=\dfrac{F\{a,b,q\}}{<<[q,a]>>}$ where $q=bd$, but I'm not sure that's helpful

Answer (score 2):

**hint:** can you use your figure to see that $X= (S^1 \vee S^1) \times S^1$?

Comment: there is a similar approach to yours [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3038850/is-lefta-b-caba-1b-1-aca-1c-1-right-the-fundamental-group-of-t?rq=1)

Comment: Yes, now that you point that it is obvious! Thanks alot.

Comment: Although, I mainly ask for a verification of my proof so that's why I don't accept (yet) your answer :)