# Hatcher Exercise 1.2.8 via the van Kampen theorem

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, path-connected

Hatcher's Exercise 1.2.8 is the following : Compute the fundamental group of the space $X$ obtained from two tori $S^1 \times S^1$ by identifying a circle $S^1 \times \{x_0\}$ in one torus with the corresponding circle $S^1 \times \{x_0\}$ in the other torus.

There are solutions on this site already, as in the discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3038850/is-lefta-b-caba-1b-1-aca-1c-1-right-the-fundamental-group-of-t?rq=1), where the original poster mentions that one needs open sets in order to apply the van Kampen theorem. I'd like to follow up on this thought with the solution I found [here](http://www.math.columbia.edu/%7Eolazarev/hw_2_solutions.pdf) (and also shown below).

[image]

Here are my questions about the provided solution:

- What allows us to take an open neighborhood of $S^1 \times \{x_0\}$ that deformation retracts onto $S^1 \times \{x_0\}$? Does any space admit such an open neighborhood that deformation retracts onto it? Or is there something special about $S^1 \times \{x_0\}$ that admits this open neighborhood?
- Applying the van Kampen theorem here requires $X$ to be the union of two path-connected open sets with path-connected intersection. How is $X$ being written as a union of two path-connected open sets here? Is $X = (T_1 \cup U_1) \cup (T_2 \cup U_2)$? If so, how can we see that $T_1 \cup U_1$ and $T_2 \cup U_2$ are path-connected and open, and have path-connected intersection?
- Below is the statement of the van Kampen theorem in Hatcher. With this in mind, it looks like the normal subgroup $N$ in the provided solution is $\pi_1(S^1)$. How can one see that this is the case?
  [image]

Thanks!

Comment: You can embed $X$ into $\Bbb R^3$ as a smaller torus inside the hole of a larger torus, with them tangent along the inner circle of the larger torus and outer circle of the inner torus. This common circle acts as $S^1 \times \{x_0\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In the more general case of two copies $A \times B$ joined by identifying the two copies of $A \times \{x_0\}$ for some $x_0 \in B$, as long as $x_0$ has a neighborhood $U$ in $B$ that deformation retracts to $\{x_0\}$, then $A \times U$ is a neighborhood of $A \times \{x_0\}$ that deformation retracts to $A \times \{x_0\}$. Every point of $S^1$ has neighborhoods isomophic to intervals on the real line. Intervals are contractible.
- There is a slip-up on the indexing in this part of the proof. Since $U_1 \subset T_1, T_1 \cup U_1 = T_1$ and similarly $T_2 \cup U_2 = T_2$. What they meant was the two open sets are $T_1 \cup U_2, T_2 \cup U_1$. Let $C = T_1 \cap T_2$ be the common circle. $T_1 \cup U_2$ is open since it is the image under the quotient of the open set $T_1 \sqcup U_2$ in $T_1 \sqcup T_2$. Similarly for $T_2\cup U_1$. Since $U_2$ retracts to $C$, $T_1 \cup U_2$ retracts to $T_1 \cup C = T_1$ and $U_1 \cup U_2$ retracts to $U_1 \cup C = U_1$, which itself retracts to $C$. Similarly $T_2 \cup U_1$ retracts to $T_2$. Since $C \cong S^1$, it is path-connected, and $T_1, T_2$ are path-connected. Since $U_1 \cup U_2$ retracts to $C$, it is also path-connected.
- The retractions above induce group isomorphisms $$\pi_1(T_1 \cup U_2) \cong \pi_1(T_1)\\\pi_1(T_2 \cup U_1) \cong \pi_1(T_2)\\\pi_1(U_1 \cup U_2) \cong \pi_1(C) \cong \pi_1(S^1)$$

Comment: Excellent. One last question -- how do we know that the normal subgroup $N$ here is $\pi_1(U_1 \cup U_2)$?

Comment: Let $x_0$ be on $C$, and let $C_1, C_2 = S^1 \times \{x_0\}$ in $T_1, T_2$ respectively. $T_1 \cong C_1 \times C, T_2 \cong C_2 \times C$ and $\pi_1(T_1) \cong \pi_1(C_1) \times \pi_1(C)$ - that is ,every loop in $T_1$ at $x_0$ is equivalent to going around $C_1$ a few times, then going around $C$ a few times. Similarly for $T_2$. But it is the same circle $C$ for both. Trips around $C$ commute with trips around either $C_1$ or $C_2$. So in $\pi_1(T_1) * \pi_1(T_2)$, you can collect all the trips around $C$ together, leaving onlty $\pi_1(C_1) * \pi_1(C_2)$.

Comment: I admit that isn't a well-stated argument. My algebra skills are pretty weak anymore, but my geometric intuition has gotten stronger, so I tend to think in that direction.